# Не получается перевести команду curl c multipart/form-data запросом в python

Tags: python-3.x, curl

У меня есть следующая команда и я хочу перевести ее на питон.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer sample"  -H "Content-Type: 
multipart/form-data; boundary=----sample" -F "file=@[object Object]" 
"https://target.my.com/api/v2/content/html5.json
```

У меня получилось следующее:

```
file = {
    'file': ('123.zip',
             open('123.zip', 'rb'))
}


headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer sample',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,compress',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----sample'
}

response = requests.post('https://target.my.com/api/v2/content/html5.json', 
files=file, headers=headers)
```

Но, почему-то, я получаю ошибку:

```
{'error': {'fields': {'file': {'message': ['Content not found in the 
request. Request must have multipart/form-data type with "file" field.'], 
'code': 'no_file'}}, 'message': 'Validation failed', 'code': 
'validation_failed'}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я мог ошибиться?

Comment: Попробуйте явно не указывать `Content-Type` в заголовках. Если не ошибаюсь, requests должен установить этот заголовок автоматически при наличии параметра `files`.

Comment: Да, все получилось. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться запросом в https://www.getpostman.com/

[image: Языки на которые Postman генерирует HTTP запросы]